# How to replace a list of strings from a file using Java?

Tags: java, replace

I have a file like this which is around 10GB in size: abc.txt

```
01 7378383 263748 927252
02 226 383833 892929
05 98283737347438 838387 892838
05 93938383873737 838383 838378
05 83635362829292 736346 736333
...
07 72828 9292828 982992
```

I have a java hash map, almost as big as the file, like this:

```
98283737347438:"ddcvsj8883kalpde2654"
93938383873737:"7hsjks7373hdehde2378"
....
83635362829292:"akjdsj8917uiskde5628"
```

I want to replace the numbers like "98283737347438" which are present for lines starting with 05 and replace them with corresponding value in map.
Final file will look like this: xyz.txt

```
01 7378383 263748 927252
02 226 383833 892929
05 ddcvsj8883kalpde2654 838387 892838
05 7hsjks7373hdehde2378 838383 838378
05 akjdsj8917uiskde5628 736346 736333
...
07 72828 9292828 982992
```

How can this be done in the most efficient way in Java/Spring Batch only ?

Comment: It may be helpful to sort the hash map file, so that you can use a binary search and avoid loading it into memory.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  Another idea would be to use a java based database such as Derby and load the hashfile into that.   http://db.apache.org/derby/

Comment: Is there any reason to believe that the "obvious" way - of reading the file line-by-line, replacing the value if necessary, then writing the result - will perform inadequately?

Comment: 4castle , Zeki - Both your ideas are very good in terms of storing the hash file. Is there a way to replace the text in the file without reading and replacing line by line ?

Comment: @DavidWallace - If there are 12 million lines in a file, then replacing the text line by line sequentially will take a long time. So I am trying to figure out an alternate way to do this.

Comment: I can't imagine any algorithm for doing this that wouldn't involve reading the whole file in sequence.  I'm not really sure what you're looking for.

Comment: I just want to replace the texts in abc.txt using the hash map.I can easily do this by sequentially reading the file line by line and replacing the text in each line and writing to a new file. However, this would be time consuming. I am just trying to see if I can optimize this in any way.

Comment: When I try to do the same thing in parallel, then I am facing 2 challenges: 
1.FlatFileWriter is not thread safe so I have to implement custom writer, but then also each thread will struggle to get lock and that process too would be slow. 
2.I can split file into multiple files, do replacement and then write to different files again. But at the end again, we will have to combine the files. That too might be too memory intensive.
Checking if any other optimized way is there.

Comment: I don't think multi-threading will help you, since this will be IO-bound, not CPU-bound.  One thing you could try is reading the file in one thread, and doing the match-replace in another.